# Svg to tikz in inkscape

Tags: python, svg, converters, tikz

I'm using inkscape to draw a simple picture and i saved with svg extension I want to convert this svg file to Tikz code for latex I download the extensions from github https://github.com/paaguti/svg2tikz and i Extract the files **tikz_export.py**, **tikz_export_effect.inx**, and **tikz_export_output.inx** from **svg2tikz-master/svg2tikz/extensions** and put them in the **share/extension** directory inside the Inkscape installation directory. when i chose **extension->exporter->export** to tikz path i get this message and nothing happen;

**

- **Inkscape a reçu des données additionnelles du script exécuté. Le
  script n’a pas retourné d’erreur, mais ceci peut indiquer que les
  résultats ne sont pas ceux attendus.**
- tikz_export.py:645: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or
  optparse has been deprecated and replaced with argparser.You must
  change self.OptionParser.add_option to self.arg_parser.add_argument;
  the arguments are similar.
- parser = self.OptionParser
- Traceback (most recent call last):
- File "tikz_export.py", line 1478, in main_inkscape()
- File "tikz_export.py", line 1461, in main_inkscape
- effect = TikZPathExporter(inkscape_mode=True) File "tikz_export.py",
  line 629, in init self._set_up_options()
- File "tikz_export.py", line 646, in _set_up_options
  parser.set_defaults(codeoutput='standalone', crop=False,
  clipboard=False, AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no
  attribute 'set_defaults'

Comment: Is this truly programming-related, since it seems you're just installing and using a piece of software? This might be more appropriate for https://superuser.com, for example. See [help/on-topic], [ask].